# Pagination in node, buttons pages

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I don't know what to do next. I made that

in angular he send quantity to skip

```
$scope.loadProducts = function (quantity) {
    $http.get("/product/products", { params: {'quantity': quantity} }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.products = resp.data;
    })
```

And in node.js he returns products list, but how to do Number of buttons what is need.

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res) {
  var count = parseInt(req.query.quantity);
  var sum = count*5;
  Product.find().skip(sum).limit(5)
    .exec(function (err, products) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(204).json({
          message: 'Can not download this list'
        })
      } else {
        if (!products.length) {
          console.log("empty")
        } else {
          res.json(products);
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: a better English would have helped understand the problem

Comment: Add a `count` query in your API which determines the number of available results and calculate the number of available pages.

Comment: But not like in this case ???  Product.find().skip(sum).limit(5).count()

Comment: No, you want to count the entire collection obviously.

Comment: how to do it, another router.get??

Comment: That depends, I would rather keep it in one API method, and return an object such as `{ results: [ … ], totalCount: 123, currentPage: 1, totalPages: 13 }`

Comment: @qqilihq Can u tell me, Can I make response with quantity all records and response products with limit? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8018004ee9acf7eb6ee16b825a53d4d5